# preg_match_all negative lookahead and negative lookbehind

Tags: php, regex

I have this pattern which starts with `(?<![\d.,])` and ends with `(?![\d.,%]| %)`

Why does it match `16` ?

I would expect it not to match anything in this string

```
$pattern = '/(?<![\d.,])-?\d{1,3}(?:(?:[. ]\d{3})*|\d*)(?:\b|[^.,%]|[,]\d{1,2})-?(?![\d.,%]| %)/';
$value = 'dag 08-16 flex pakke';

echo "pattern: $pattern\nvalue: $value\n";

preg_match_all($pattern, $value, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/KDgbjl/1, but if you explain your requirements, it could help to come up with a cleaner regex.

Comment: Comment your regex and make it multiline with the `/x` flag.

Comment: Maybe you need to include `-` in the negative lookbehind? `(?<![\d.,-])`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, create an answer.. your lookbehind helped me on the right path :)

Comment: Please also consider upvoting my answer if it turned out helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lookarounds stand next to optional patterns, `-?`. Thus, whenever the lookarounds fail, backtracking occurs, and the unwelcome matches occur.

To avoid this, account for the optional pattern *inside* the lookaround patterns.

```
/-?(?<![\d.,]-|[\d.,])\d{1,3}(?:(?:[. ]\d{3})*|\d*)(?:\b|[^.,%]|,\d{1,2})(?!-?(?:[\d.,%]| %))-?/
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KDgbjl/1)